# Convert .xls files of multiple sheets to .xlsx

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have a 97-2003 `.xls` excel file that I need to converted to a `.xlsx`. The operational sense is that I have a plethora of these I need to convert.

My issue is that each `.xls` file has various sheets; both the number and sheet names change.

I am trying to convert the `.xls` to `.xlsx` extension using Python. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18495672/how-to-iterate-over-worksheets-in-workbook-openpyxl) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26521266/using-pandas-to-pd-read-excel-for-multiple-worksheets-of-the-same-workbook) and [this `pandas` page](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.ExcelWriter.html#pandas.ExcelWriter) have led me to believe using [`Openpyxl`](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) is a good solution for this. My current code looks like:

```
import pandas as pd, xlrd, openpyxl
filename = 'STAGING FILE1.XLS'
xlsx_filename = "temp_output.xlsx"

xls_file = pd.ExcelFile(filename)

with pd.ExcelWriter(xlsx_filename) as writer:
    for sheet in xls_file.sheet_names:
        df = pd.read_excel(pd.read_excel(filename, sheet_name=sheet))
        df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=sheet)
```

Please note, none of these libraries are hard requirements; just what I *think* is my best chance at solving this problem.

However, I am getting `IndexError: At least one sheet must be visible`, with a full traceback below. How can I properly accomplish switching the extension from `.XLS` to `.xlsx`?

Full traceback:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [13], in <module>
----> 1 dma_hh = wb[wb.worksheets[0]]

File filepath\Excel Formatting\_venv\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\workbook\workbook.py:288, in Workbook.__getitem__(self, key)
    286     if sheet.title == key:
    287         return sheet
--> 288 raise KeyError("Worksheet {0} does not exist.".format(key))

KeyError: 'Worksheet <Worksheet "Sheet1"> does not exist.'
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [5], in <module>
      4 for sheet in xls_file.sheet_names:
----> 5     df = pd.read_excel(pd.read_excel(filename, sheet_name=sheet))
      6     df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=sheet)

File filepath\Excel Formatting\_venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py:311, in deprecate_nonkeyword_arguments.<locals>.decorate.<locals>.wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    306     warnings.warn(
    307         msg.format(arguments=arguments),
    308         FutureWarning,
    309         stacklevel=stacklevel,
    310     )
--> 311 return func(*args, **kwargs)

File filepath\Excel Formatting\_venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_base.py:364, in read_excel(io, sheet_name, header, names, index_col, usecols, squeeze, dtype, engine, converters, true_values, false_values, skiprows, nrows, na_values, keep_default_na, na_filter, verbose, parse_dates, date_parser, thousands, comment, skipfooter, convert_float, mangle_dupe_cols, storage_options)
    363     should_close = True
--> 364     io = ExcelFile(io, storage_options=storage_options, engine=engine)
    365 elif engine and engine != io.engine:

File filepath\Excel Formatting\_venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_base.py:1191, in ExcelFile.__init__(self, path_or_buffer, engine, storage_options)
   1190 else:
-> 1191     ext = inspect_excel_format(
   1192         content_or_path=path_or_buffer, storage_options=storage_options
   1193     )
   1194     if ext is None:

File filepath\Excel Formatting\_venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_base.py:1070, in inspect_excel_format(content_or_path, storage_options)
   1068     content_or_path = BytesIO(content_or_path)
-> 1070 with get_handle(
   1071     content_or_path, "rb", storage_options=storage_options, is_text=False
   1072 ) as handle:
   1073     stream = handle.handle

File filepath\Excel Formatting\_venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\common.py:609, in get_handle(path_or_buf, mode, encoding, compression, memory_map, is_text, errors, storage_options)
    608 # open URLs
--> 609 ioargs = _get_filepath_or_buffer(
    610     path_or_buf,
    611     encoding=encoding,
    612     compression=compression,
    613     mode=mode,
    614     storage_options=storage_options,
    615 )
    617 handle = ioargs.filepath_or_buffer

File filepath\Excel Formatting\_venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\common.py:396, in _get_filepath_or_buffer(filepath_or_buffer, encoding, compression, mode, storage_options)
    395     msg = f"Invalid file path or buffer object type: {type(filepath_or_buffer)}"
--> 396     raise ValueError(msg)
    398 return IOArgs(
    399     filepath_or_buffer=filepath_or_buffer,
    400     encoding=encoding,
   (...)
    403     mode=mode,
    404 )

ValueError: Invalid file path or buffer object type: <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [5], in <module>
      4 for sheet in xls_file.sheet_names:
      5     df = pd.read_excel(pd.read_excel(filename, sheet_name=sheet))
----> 6     df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=sheet)

File filepath\Excel Formatting\_venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_base.py:1020, in ExcelWriter.__exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback)
   1019 def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback):
-> 1020     self.close()

File filepath\Excel Formatting\_venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_base.py:1024, in ExcelWriter.close(self)
   1022 def close(self):
   1023     """synonym for save, to make it more file-like"""
-> 1024     content = self.save()
   1025     self.handles.close()
   1026     return content

File filepath\Excel Formatting\_venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_openpyxl.py:80, in OpenpyxlWriter.save(self)
     76 def save(self):
     77     """
     78     Save workbook to disk.
     79     """
---> 80     self.book.save(self.handles.handle)
     81     if "r+" in self.mode and not isinstance(self.handles.handle, mmap.mmap):
     82         # truncate file to the written content
     83         self.handles.handle.truncate()

File filepath\Excel Formatting\_venv\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\workbook\workbook.py:407, in Workbook.save(self, filename)
    405 if self.write_only and not self.worksheets:
    406     self.create_sheet()
--> 407 save_workbook(self, filename)

File filepath\Excel Formatting\_venv\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\writer\excel.py:293, in save_workbook(workbook, filename)
    291 archive = ZipFile(filename, 'w', ZIP_DEFLATED, allowZip64=True)
    292 writer = ExcelWriter(workbook, archive)
--> 293 writer.save()
    294 return True

File filepath\Excel Formatting\_venv\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\writer\excel.py:275, in ExcelWriter.save(self)
    273 def save(self):
    274     """Write data into the archive."""
--> 275     self.write_data()
    276     self._archive.close()

File filepath\Excel Formatting\_venv\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\writer\excel.py:89, in ExcelWriter.write_data(self)
     87 writer = WorkbookWriter(self.workbook)
     88 archive.writestr(ARC_ROOT_RELS, writer.write_root_rels())
---> 89 archive.writestr(ARC_WORKBOOK, writer.write())
     90 archive.writestr(ARC_WORKBOOK_RELS, writer.write_rels())
     92 self._merge_vba()

File filepath\Excel Formatting\_venv\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\workbook\_writer.py:148, in WorkbookWriter.write(self)
    146 self.write_names()
    147 self.write_pivots()
--> 148 self.write_views()
    149 self.write_refs()
    151 return tostring(self.package.to_tree())

File filepath\Excel Formatting\_venv\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\workbook\_writer.py:135, in WorkbookWriter.write_views(self)
    134 def write_views(self):
--> 135     active = get_active_sheet(self.wb)
    136     if self.wb.views:
    137         self.wb.views[0].activeTab = active

File filepath\Excel Formatting\_venv\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\workbook\_writer.py:33, in get_active_sheet(wb)
     31 visible_sheets = [idx for idx, sheet in enumerate(wb._sheets) if sheet.sheet_state == "visible"]
     32 if not visible_sheets:
---> 33     raise IndexError("At least one sheet must be visible")
     35 idx = wb._active_sheet_index
     36 sheet = wb.active

IndexError: At least one sheet must be visible
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following solution works and was inspired [by this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35707723/writing-multiple-pandas-dataframes-to-multiple-excel-worksheets) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53290765/convert-a-xlsx-file-with-multiple-sheets-to-multiple-xlsx-files):

```
import pandas as pd, gc as gc
gc.enable()
filename = 'STAGING FILE1.XLS'
xlsx_filename = "temp_output.xlsx"

xls_file = pd.ExcelFile(filename)

# Create ExcelFile object and retrieve sheet names
xls_file = pd.ExcelFile(filename)
sheet_names = xls_file.sheet_names

# Create dict
res = {}

# Build dict of sheetname: dataframe of each sheet
for sheet in sheet_names:
    res[sheet] = pd.read_excel(filename, sheet_name=sheet, header=None)

# Create ExcelWriter object
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(xlsx_filename, engine='xlsxwriter')

# Loop through dict, and have the writer write them to a single file
for sheet, frame in res.items():
    frame.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=sheet, header=None, index=None)

# Save off
writer.save()
    
# Delete objects and free up memory
del xls_file, sheet_names, res, writer
gc.collect()
```

Comment: Excellent solution! It helped me resolve my own issue with the same problem. I would suggest that you can use this line: 
    df = pd.read_excel(response['Body'].read(),sheet_name=None)
to create the dictionary of sheetnames and dataframes...

Then loop over it like this:
    for key, value in df.items():
        value.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=key, index = False)